# Updating multiple rows previous to a particular date

Tags: sql-server

I'm working with a website that had an update done to its business layer, so now I need to convert the old data to match the way new data is saved. I'm writing a SQL query that updates a couple of data columns on a member table, where the person_id matches on the member and registration code tables, an registration code is present on the reg cod table, and that reg code is flagged as used before a certain date on the reg code table.

```
UPDATE vs_member
SET premium_acct = 1, tenant_reg_key = (
SELECT DISTINCT tenant_reg_key 
FROM vs_tenant_reg_key_tbl t
WHERE person_id = t.person_id)
WHERE person_id in (
SELECT t2.person_id
FROM vs_tenant_reg_key_tbl t2
WHERE person_id = t2.person_id AND t2.used = 1 AND premium_acct = 0 AND date_joined <= '2013-11-08')
```

I'm receiving an error stating the following: **Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.**

Not exactly sure how to handle that, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your subselect, `WHERE person_id = t.person_id` probably isn't doing what you think.

Consider writing your `UPDATE` statement using joins instead of subselects. Perhaps something like this would do what you want.

```
UPDATE V
   SET premium_acct = 1, tenant_reg_key = T.tenant_reg_key
  FROM vs_member V
  INNER JOIN vs_tenant_reg_key_tbl T ON T.person_id = V.person_id
  WHERE T.used = 1 AND T.premium_acct = 0 AND T.date_joined < '2013-11-08'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following part of your query is returning more than one entry:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tenant_reg_key 
FROM vs_tenant_reg_key_tbl t
WHERE person_id = t.person_id
```

If so, you won't be able to set tenant_reg_key to the results of this query, as it's essentially trying to add more than one value -- once, mind you -- to one entry.